# Submitting form with requests doesn't go through

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've really tried to solve this problem on my own but I am novice at pyhon, so I were not able to do that. I've been trying to make a bot for a website I use and I am trying to do so using requests library. So far my goals are pretty simple: log in and reply to a thread.

I've been able to log in through web form, but I am having some troubles replying to a thread by submitting a form. 
At first my code looked like that:

```
   payload = {
        'post': 'Send'
        'message': message
    }

    response = self.session.post(reply_url, data=payload)
```

where 'Send' is name of the submit button. Request is actually submitted, but it encounters an error. So I've looked for hidden fields, and I found them:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="topic_cur_post_id" value="75855" />
   <input type="hidden" name="creation_time" value="1472760834" />
   <input type="hidden" name="lastclick" value="1472761028" />
   <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="0ba9f5b8e091367fa38ad8db68424a1adb62d299" />
```

So basically I am now gathering all those informations first with GET request and my code now looks like that:

```
    payload = {
        'post': 'Send'
        'message': message, 
        'form_token': form_token, 
        'topic_cur_post_id': topic_cur_post_id, 
        'lastclick': lastclick,
        'creation_time': creation_time 
    }

    response = self.session.post(reply_url, data=payload)
```

Right now I am not encountering any error and I am being redirected as if my reply was submitted. The things is - it's not. I double checked if my payload is solid, and it is.
The weird things is... if I attempt to execute the exact same code next, only with 'lastclick' removed, it actually goes through! But only for few attempts. Then I have to add 'lastclicks' back to the payload, execute the code, then remove it and only then does it work.

It's been a real headscratcher for me guys. If anybody has some clues or ideas, I'd be glad to hear it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess that the lastclick parameter is some kind of token to prevent you from doing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I would suggest you to request the site containing the hidden inputs, extracting them with [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)  and using the parsed ones. This is exactly what your browser does, so it should work as expected. Edit: seems like you are doing that. What is `lastclick` if the hidden input is not present?

Comment: Thanks guys, I've resolved the problem. If anyone encounters something similar in the future, the answer was waiting a few seconds between requests. Apparently there's some kind of cooldown and you can send get and post request one after the other.