# Module 'requests' doesn't go through with the login

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, python-requests

I am trying to get information from a website by using the `requests` module. To get to the information you have to be logged in and then you can access the page. I looked into the input tags and noticed that they are called `login_username` and `login_password` but for some reasons the `post` doesn't go through. I also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280393/submitting-form-with-requests-doesnt-go-through) that he solved it by waiting for few seconds before going thorugh the other page, it didn't helped either..

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import time

#This URL will be the URL that your login form points to with the "action" tag.
loginurl = 'https://jadepanel.nephrite.ro/login'

#This URL is the page you actually want to pull down with requests.
requesturl = 'https://jadepanel.nephrite.ro/clan/view/123'

payload = {
    'login_username': 'username',
    'login_password': 'password'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(loginurl, data=payload)
    time.sleep(3)
    r = session.get(requesturl)
    print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`login_username` and `login_password` are not all the necessary parameters. If you look at the `/login/` POST request in the browser developer tools, you would see that there is also a `_token` being sent.

This is something you would need to *parse out of the login HTML*. So the flow would be the following:

- get the `https://jadepanel.nephrite.ro/login` page
- HTML parse it and extract `_token` value
- make a POST request with login, password and token
- use the logged in session to navigate the site

For the HTML parsing we could use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (there are other options, of course):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_html = session.get(loginurl).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(login_html, "html.parser")

token = soup.find("input", {"name": "_token"})["value"]

payload = {
    'login_username': 'username',
    'login_password': 'password',
    '_token': token
}
```

---

Complete code:

```
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# This URL will be the URL that your login form points to with the "action" tag.
loginurl = 'https://jadepanel.nephrite.ro/login'

# This URL is the page you actually want to pull down with requests.
requesturl = 'https://jadepanel.nephrite.ro/clan/view/123'

with requests.Session() as session:
    login_html = session.get(loginurl).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(login_html, "html.parser")

    token = soup.find("input", {"name": "_token"})["value"]

    payload = {
        'login_username': 'username',
        'login_password': 'password',
        '_token': token
    }

    post = session.post(loginurl, data=payload)
    time.sleep(3)
    r = session.get(requesturl)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: hey @alecxe, thank you for your answer. I am a newbie in python3 and I don't have any ideea how I could include the token into my script to work it properly. Could you please insert that into my code? I tried to do that by myself but for some reasons I get an `    soup = BeautifulSoup(login_html, "html.parser")
                                                  ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` even tho there isn't a tab there.

Comment: @SirFulgeruL sure, just added the complete code, hope that helps.

Comment: thank you , sadly it still doesn't work as the output that I get is the login page not the information from the `requesturl`.

Comment: @SirFulgeruL okay, so, token was probably only a part of the problem. First of all, make sure you have correct login and password. Also, if you inspect the `post` value - what is the `post.status_code` and `post.content`? Thanks.

Comment: the `post.status_code` is 302 and the `post.content` is `_token=HFGFjYuA5yLiCPQC3tNVEvdgthTro4ECj1on9hK
login_username=username
login_password=password
user_identifier=8e565c1c9ee4bd7f57905f20ad598584` .

Comment: thanks the the post.content that I gave you I added `used_identifier` into payload and it worked. Thank you so much for you help.